# NG-Bootstrap - Dropdown - Select Value

Tags: electron, ng-bootstrap

I'm using this code for the dropdown menu for my Electron App currently:

```
 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Selected Value</button>
                            <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
                                <button class="dropdown-item">Example A</button>
                                <button class="dropdown-item">Example B</button>
                                <button class="dropdown-item">Example C</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I found it here:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples

What I want is, if I click on Example A, I want this to show as the Selected Value. So instead of "Selected Value" there is "Example A" then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation for this. In your TS file, you can do:

```
selectedValue: string = 'Selected Value';
```

In your HTML file, you can do:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>{{selectedValue}}</button>
```

and

```
<button class="dropdown-item" (click)="changeDropdownName('Example A')">Example A</button>
```

Then add the changeDropdownName function to your TS file:

```
changeDropdownName(value: string) {
this.selectedValue = value;
}
```